# How to add text tag in Audio in Android

Tags: android, tags, audio-recording

I want to build an app which records an audio and user should have the option to insert (add) some text based tag in Audio. For example the user is in meeting or class and records whatever is being discussed there and sometime he/she finds some important point in that topic and adds a text based tag (a message) to remember later.

And when at later time he/she plays that audio then he/she can view all the added tags and can directly go to that point (which he/she had tagged) by clicking that text of particular tag and the audio should start playing (or the seek bar should be moved) at that particular time.

In this way user can add as many tags as he/she wants and can go directly (and listen) to audio at that particular time (place on seek bar).

I don't know whether it is possible or not. So can anyone kindly tell whether it's possible. And if yes, then how can I do that. And please excuse me if its a stupid question.

Comment: You can do it manually: for each recorded audio file write a textfile that contains timestamp & text for each tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my idea:

- create a database with columns recordingName, recordingTag and tagBeginning
- when a user creates a new tag you remember a time passed from begining of the recording
- when recording is finished put tags and times in database (you wll have more rows with the same recording name)
- when you want to play a file query your database with your recording names; you will get your tags and their beginning times
- use beginning times to know where to start playing certain recording